# ReactJS won't print an array in the order that it is stored?

Tags: reactjs

I have an issue with my reactjs code where the render() function won't print an array in the order that it is stored in my state object.

Here's my code which is pretty simple:

```js
import React from "react";

export default class DonationDetail extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { content: [] };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let state = this.state;
    state.content.push({ food: "burger" });
    state.content.push({ food: "pizza" });
    state.content.push({ food: "tacos" });
    this.setState(state);
  }

  addPaymentItem() {
    const item = { food: "" };
    let state = this.state;
    state.content.unshift(item);
    this.setState(state);
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state);
    let ui = (
      <div>
        <button type="button" onClick={() => this.addPaymentItem()}>
          add to top
        </button>
        {this.state.content.map((item, key) => (
          <input type="text" key={key} defaultValue={item.food} />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
    return ui;
  }
}
```

When you press the button `add to top`, a new item is placed to the front of the `state.content` array, which you can verify from the `console.log(this.state)` statement.   But what's unusual is that the HTML that is generated does NOT add this new item to the top of the user interface output.  Instead, another input field with the word taco is placed at the bottom of the list in the user interface.

Why won't ReactJS print my `state.content` array in the order that it is actually stored?

Comment: you are using state incorrectly. you should never mutate the state object directly. you want to use `this.setState()` and either pass it a new object with the calculated state, or a function that returns an object with the updated state. also, you don't want to use an integer index as `key` during rendering - name it something useful like `\`content-${key}\``

Comment: @Derek - I did use setState() each time I was mutating it.  I also tried changing the key as your suggested but the outcome is still the same, the list of items rendered does not reflect the order of the state.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: Using the array index as key is a known anti pattern because of how react's reconciliation works. Check here for more details: https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the array index as `key` when the order of the elements in the array will not change, but when you add an element to the beginning of the array the order is changed.

You could add a unique `id` to all your foods and use that as `key` instead.

**Example**

```js
class DonationDetail extends React.Component {
  state = { content: [] };

  componentDidMount() {
    const content = [];

    content.push({ id: 1, food: "burger" });
    content.push({ id: 2, food: "pizza" });
    content.push({ id: 3, food: "tacos" });

    this.setState({ content });
  }

  addPaymentItem = () => {
    const item = { id: Math.random(), food: "" };
    this.setState(prevState => ({ content: [item, ...prevState.content] }));
  };

  handleChange = (event, index) => {
    const { value } = event.target;
    this.setState(prevState => {
      const content = [...prevState.content];

      content[index] = { ...content[index], food: value };

      return { content };
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button type="button" onClick={this.addPaymentItem}>
          add to top
        </button>
        {this.state.content.map((item, index) => (
          <input
            type="text"
            key={item.id}
            value={item.food}
            onChange={event => this.handleChange(event, index)}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<DonationDetail />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
componentDidMount() {
  let state = this.state;
  state.content.push({ food: "burger" });
  state.content.push({ food: "pizza" });
  state.content.push({ food: "tacos" });
  this.setState(state);
}
```

Try

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    content: [
      ...prevState.content,
      { food: "burger" },
      { food: "pizza" },
      { food: "tacos" },
    ]
  }));
}
```

and

```
addPaymentItem() {
  const item = { food: "" };
  let state = this.state;
  state.content.unshift(item);
  this.setState(state);
}
```

to

```
addPaymentItem() {
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    content: [
      { food: "" },
      ...prevState.content,
    ]
  }));
}
```